# Tabela que muda de cor

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, css

Boa tarde à todos, sou iniciante em php gostaria de saber como mudo a cor de uma tabela que recebe as informações do banco de dados. Por exemplo tenho uma ficha de intervenção técnica onde tenho o status pendente e concluído, quero que quando a coluna status receber concluído que fique verde e caso receba pendente ficaria vermelha, segue o código:

```
<?php
    require_once("conexao.php");
    $comando = "SELECT * FROM fit";
    $enviar=mysqli_query($conn, $comando);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($enviar, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>


<style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: left;
    }

    table, tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #eee;
    }

</style>

<div class="table" style="width:100%">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Técnico</th>
        <th>Estação</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>

<?php
    foreach ($resultado as $fit) {
        $id=$fit['id'];
        $tecnico=$fit['tecnico'];
        $estacao=$fit['estacao'];
        $status=$fit['situacao'];

?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$id?></td>
        <td><?=$tecnico?></td>
        <td><?=$estacao?></td>
        <td><?=$status?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, crie uma classe no seu CSS para estilizar cada `status` do seu registro:

```
td.pendente {
    background-color: red;
}
td.concluido {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Agora, basta adicionar esse estilo na coluna conforme o `status` do registro em questão:

```
//...
<tr>
    <td><?=$id?></td>
    <td><?=$tecnico?></td>
    <td><?=$estacao?></td>
    <td class="<?= ($status == 'concluido' ? 'concluido' : 'pendente'); ?>"><?=$status?></td>
</tr>
//...
```

Nesse primeiro `'concluido'` em `$status == 'concluido'` vai ser feita uma comparação com o que vai vir da sua consulta. Logo, ajuste conforme seus registros.

Se ficar em dúvida sobre o operador `?:`, vou deixar um link que te explica exatamente como usar.

> Leitura recomendada: [PHP - Operador ternário](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta foi de muita grande ajuda. Como seria se talves eu quiser com que a linha inteira concluido ficasse verde e pendente vermelha, não só a coluna como havia dito no caso a linha inteira

Comment: @vinicius primeiro busque entender a solução proposta na minha resposta. Perceba que eu estilizei uma coluna (`td`). Se você quer estilizar toda a linha, leve esta estilização para a linha (`tr`). Se, ainda assim, tiver dificuldade, comente aqui que complementarei a resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, consegui o que queria.Grande abraço.